# How to handle a high-pressure offer deadline

Tags: job-offer

I received a verbal offer from one of the companies I've been interviewing with on Monday and they wanted me to give them a decision "by the end of the week".  I explained that I am currently interviewing with at least two other companies and have a third that is supposed to extend me an offer or decline sometime this week and they extended their deadline to the following Tuesday.

Not only does it feel like a very short time to consider the position (job doesn't even start until August) but he said they won't type up a formal letter until/unless I verbally accept the verbal offer.

Until this point the company was pretty high on my list of companies I want to work for but I feel like I just left the used car lot.

So far I feel like my main 2 options are to either tell them flat out that I'm still interested in working for them but can't make a final decision in the time allowed or to verbally accept as a bid to buy some time while I wait for the formal letter before making a final decision.

Comment: [This answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/5860/2322) is quite helpful. As well as [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/5861/2322).

Comment: They won't give you a formal offer in writing until you verbally accept what they've offered you verbally? That sounds *really* shady, like they want to leave themselves room to completely change the terms but have you locked in. If you verbally accept, and the formal letter isn't what you're expecting, what do you do? What recourse do you have?

Comment: Agreed, if it's not in writing, it's not an offer. They need to make an offer before they get antsy about how quickly or slowly you accept their offer.

Comment: You have little to lose by saying yes.  As noted if its not in writing it really is not enforceable.  If you find another position you would prefer before this one starts then you can reject this position then.

Comment: Let's say you have three possible positions to join. You might assume that one is above average, one is average, one is below average. With enough time you pick the best one, which is above average. If you accept the time pressure, you will only consider that job. To accept it, the job offer would have to be above average, otherwise rejecting it and waiting for the other two offers gives you a better chance.