# How can I manage applying for 2 more jobs when I already have a part time job?

Tags: human-resources

I have had a job for almost 1 year now.(job A) I'm an RN. I only work in this hospital once a week. I applied for several jobs to add hours, because I only work 12 hours per week.

First, I was offered and had a physical on Monday (job B)on one of the hospitals that I applied (part time also, once a week)The problem is one company that I had been applying for years suddenly called me to have an interview on a Wednesday of the same week.(Job  C) Luckily, I got the job, and an offer pending physical and background check. (Job C)

The problem is that Job C, which is my dream job, wants a full-time commitment.(job C) The hospital orientation for my other new job will be this Friday. (Job B)

The question is this: Do I need to attend this hospital orientation (job B) knowing that in 2 weeks pending background check and physical, if everything goes fine, I will have to quit this new job because my 3rd (job C) wants my full-time commitment?  They already gave me a starting date on the offer letter(job C).

If ever do I need to pass a resignation letter to this other new job,(B)if I quit before hospital orientation, or should I just talk to the HR, that I'll be quitting and will not pursue my orientation anymore since it haven't started yet, I just had only physical last Monday. I am thinking its more fair to the 2nd employer,(B) for me not to attend anymore the hospital orientation on Friday.(Job B)Tomorrow is Thursday already, I have to decide tonight.

Comment: Hey Donald, welcome to the Workplace SE! I'm a little confused and not sure which job you're referring to in each case. (I think you have 3 jobs). Can you maybe [edit] you post and label them Job A, Job B, and Job C and make it clear which one you currently hold and which one you're applying for/receiving the offer?  With that said, I'm not 100% sure you're question is a good fit for our format, but editing will definitely help us better determine that. Good luck, and welcome! :)

Comment: @Donald - You shouldn't close any doors.  The best solution is to request your orientation be delayed by 2 weeks.  This will allow yourself a small window of time to get a response from Job C but not entirely close the doors on Job B since Job C is far from certain.

Comment: This may be helpful as well: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to attend this hospital orientation (job B) knowing that in 2 weeks pending background check and physical, if everything goes fine, I will have to quit this new job because my 3rd (job C) wants my full-time commitment?

[A bird at hand](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-bird-in-the-hand.html) and all that. Meaning - job C is **pending** and is not certain, while job B is certain. You don't want to compromise it in case job C falls through, in which case you will end up with no job B or job C.

I understand that this is a bit of a moral dilemma, in that you don't want to lead job B on and have them waste resources, but you do need to consider the worst case scenario with job C (for some reason something either goes wrong with the physical and background check or they get delayed).