# How do I politely defer a job offer acceptance or ask for a faster decision?

Tags: job-offer

I am interviewing for two positions in which I feel I have a strong lead. Both jobs involve relocation. I have a preferred job. I think I will receive an offer from my less preferred job first.

Can I ask to wait a week or two before saying yes or will that compromise my offer? Should I tentatively say yes but ask for a month or more before starting and politely inform them that I've received an offer from a better one if that comes beforehand?

Is it polite to tell others that I need a decision before a certain time point?

What's the best way to delegate this issue?

Comment: What differences are there from [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)?

Answer (score 0):

**Honesty is the best policy.** But, **You don't have to tell everybody everything !**

Let's call your preferred company A, your less preferred company B.

You tell both A and B that you're waiting for an offer from more than one company. Don't tell them the other company's name.

If A wants you or is undecided, they'll speed up the process. If A does not want you, they'll keep quiet or say something like "Good luck!". Either way, you know what's happening sooner.

The same applies to B. So, you get to decide which one you'll work for sooner.

Every company is different. They have their own procedures. Some make decisions very fast. Some have slow process. I had this experience, I got a call from a company asking me if I was still looking for job 6 months after I started my then new job. So, if you really want to work for A, wait patiently after you tell them you're waiting for an offer and did not have negative response from them.