# A new job negotiation dilemma when another interview is pending

Tags: interviewing, new-job, negotiation, job-offer

I am in a process of finding myself a new job as a software developer. The first interview went reasonably well and today I got a response asking when could I start.

The thing is, the contract terms they offered are not entirely 100% in the "But It Now" category and I have another interview in a different company coming up this week.

Unfortunately I have no idea how will that one play out which puts me into a dilemma - on the one hand, I am curious about outcome of the next interview, but on the other hand, I want to keep my current opportunity open without damaging it in any significant sense.

Has anyone been in this situation before? What questions should I be asking myself when looking for a solution to this dilemma while remaining honest towards potential employers but at the same time keeping my options as open as possible?

Comment: Does [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa) give you enough information to answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with going for many interviews around the same time, any employer will be able to respect that they're not the only employer in the market. However, I would only reveal that information if there was no other option. Nobody likes to feel second best.

I'd say the best bet is to tell Employer A when you're available to start (in a few weeks, since then there is time to hear back from Employer B). Then, depending on how things go with Employer B, you can either accept the job with Employer B, or carry on with Employer A, as if this was never an issue.

By doing this, you can ensure that you are burning as little bridges as possible, while keeping your options open.

Remember, nothing is set in stone, and you're free to change your mind until contracts are signed.