# How to get more time to wait for other job offer ?

Tags: job-offer

I had an interview with company A (4 days ago). The manager called me yesterday to go back today to talk about the paid. But I had an interview today, so I told him that I need to see a doctor. For sure, any person would know the truth, but I don't like the job.

I had an interview with company B (8 days ago), the boss like me. I also love to work there. He told me that as long as he receive the deal, he would bring me in. I sent a follow up email yesterday, but I have not yet get any response.

I had an interview with company C (11 days ago), the manager said that I might need to interview with the owner. He told me that the owner was out of town for a business trip. I am fine to work there. I sent a follow up email yesterday, but I have not yet get any response.

I had an interview with company D (Today), I like to work there. I also told the manager that I got an offer. The manager like me, but he said that is a big company. It would take some time if he would be able to send out the offer.

How I can get more time from company A? I need work to bring in money, but I don't want to do something that I don't like.

Also what I should do with company B, C, & D?

Comment: Does [this very similar question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/2322) help?

Comment: Which job do you like more A, B, C or D.?

Comment: Best   B>D>C>A   Least

Comment: You shouldn't have lied to A; had they withdrawn their offer for interviewing with multiple companies, you'd have known for sure you don't want to work there.

Answer (score 2):

On your first question: how can I get more time from company A - I would say - Just ask for it. Be honest. Just say you need a little more time to consider your career choices. The effect? If they really like you, they will probably give you a few days - but they have a business to run, so it will not be a long time. If they just consider you to be an "okay" candidate, they will tell you they can't wait, and pressure you to give them an answer or they will just move on to the next person in line.

On your second question: what you should do about companies B, C and D - you need to establish a limit date for each one of them - how many days are you able/willing to wait for each one of those companies to get in touch with you? Start from there, then make your decision. It is a good practice to always reach out to a candidate with an answer - either a positive or negative one - but unfortunately it's not all companies that follow good practices, so you may never hear from them again. Be prepared for that. In case you do get a positive answer from one of them - same thing applies as in question #1: if it wasn't your favorite who made you an offer and you want more time to wait for another company, just ask for it. But always bear in mind that when negotiating there is always a risk the other part will not agree and it may jeopardize your chances with them. It all depends on how much you want - or don't want - to work on each of those companies.

Also, if I can add an opinion - you already said you don't want to work for company A. Would you be happy there? Would you be committed? Would you be doing your best? If not, why are you still considering it? Maybe the honest thing to do for yourself and for that company is to just withdraw or decline from the process. And they can move on to find someone who is better suited for the job (in terms of actually wanting it).