# Salary offer with current company, but other place wants to do second interview?

Tags: career-development, job-offer

Right now I am working part-time, but last Friday my boss offered a salaried position.  However, I started interviewing with another company last Thursday because I do not enjoy my current job and have been job hunting for a while.  I did well on the interview and they want a 2nd interview on Monday.

The problem is that my current boss wants an answer about my salary decision tomorrow (Wednesday).  I really want to do this other interview, but they have not made an offer or discussed salary.

What is the best way to handle this situation?  Is it rude to accept their salary and still interview with another company, then quit?  Or should I tell my boss the truth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: @Chad I really don't think that other question is the same at all, but okay.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My boss is very firm about getting me to work salaried so he can send me off to travel, which I don't want to do. It's controls engineering work in airports.

Comment: Its not rude its business.  Do you think your company would keep you around if it needed to save the money that you cost them?  But the practical question that we can answer here is the same.

Comment: If you do decide to accept the current offer, but still pursue the other, make sure there is nothing in the employment contract that will hold you accountable to either time or money at that job.  Some companies will stipulate that certain things have to be re-imbursed if you leave within a certain time frame (usually a year).  Additionally, you will likely be burning a bridge with that company, but that is possible either way really.

Comment: @ElectricSquidInk If the only reason your boss wants you full-time is to allow you to do something you don't want to do, you should probably discuss that with him before accepting anything. It could be that they'd rather keep you part-time than have you be unhappy full-time (and soon leave).

Comment: ["You discover that duplicate only looks similar..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I would do is tell the current boss that I need more time. If it comes to it, mention that you might have another offer. The thing is that expecting an answer the next day is pretty unreasonable, and is quite often done precisely to not give you enough time to consider other offers.

You also mentioned that you don't like your current job, and for me that's a very good reason to go all the way with the other opportunity.

Accepting the position and interviewing elsewhere is a valid option, although personally I'd prefer to negotiate if possible. Your current boss certainly won't like it if you were to accept and then leave after a week or two, but companies see their own interests, and you have to see to your own.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for money above happiness? Simple question. If yes, take the salary, and be happy with it. Know, however, that a truly salaried individual is not tied to hours. You'll work more hours with no overtime. It is just the way it is.

However, since you are not happy at your current company, if money is not the main driver, interview is your way out. A second interview shows (more) serious interest in you as a candidate. You really won't know, however, until you get an offer letter.

Comment: Your statement "you'll work more hours with no overtime. It is just the way it is" is presented without any sort of proof. Anecdotally, I disprove it every year. I am a salaried, non-overtime-eligible employee who on average keeps to a 40-hour work week. Your statement is certainly true *of some companies and positions*, but without more detail about this particular company, your claim is speculation.

Comment: I do not disagree.