# Regarding notice period;getting interviewed by third company

Tags: interviewing, india, notice-period

I am going to complete my notice period with my current employer this weekend and going to join my second company next week. Meanwhile I am going thru' interview process of a third company which is much better and I have cleared some phases also and I haven't communicated regarded my notice period to this organisation. What I am thinking if I get selected by next week or so then I will abscond from the organisation which I am gonna join next week. But I am utterly confused what should I do, I mean if right now I tell the organisation with which I am getting interviewed that my notice period is gonna over this week, they might consider cancellation of my candidature. Is that bound to happen or it will be ok if I explain these things when this interview process is over ??..pls help

Comment: This appears to be identical to this question - [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: Why downvote.. There is nothing regarding notice period mentioned in that post... Thats rude.

Comment: "This question does nto show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is the hover-over for the downvote. My guess is someone found a lot of text written in a single paragraph without any punctuation and no clear question to meet these criteria.

Comment: @cbinder I read [the post](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa) enderland mentioned and you can easily transfer the answer there to your problem. That's why it's unlikely that you'll get answers here since your problem is **highly similar**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean if right now I tell the organisation with which I am getting
>   interviewed that my notice period is gonna over this week, they might
>   consider cancellation of my candidature. Is that bound to happen or it
>   will be ok if I explain these things when this interview process is
>   over ??..pls help

I don't see what you have to gain by telling the "third company" anything. They might indeed think less of you if they learn about your plans.

You have already given your notice to the "first company" and will be gone this weekend.

You have already decided to stiff the "second company" by joining them next week even if you intend to leave upon getting another offer.

What would compel you to treat this "third company" any better than the "second"?

Just remain quiet and hope your plan works out as you expect. If not, then you are safely in the employ of the "second company" and nobody is the wiser. Then you can move on to a "fourth company" if you so choose.

(Note: I'm not trying to suggest that joining a company when you intend to leave shortly is a good idea or not. It's not what I'd do, but you've already made that choice. I'm just trying to answer your question.)

Comment: Hmm...getting your point. The compelling point is that I had decided to take pay cut to join 2nd one because of bad work culture in my present one and this 3rd one will surely pay more than my present one.