# Is it appropriate to let a slow moving recruiter know that you are interviewing with other employers?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I interviewed with a recruiter from a large firm more than 2 weeks ago. She had expressed that the hiring director had seen my resume wanted me to be screened. The recruiter is an employee of the large firm.

After the interview, she stated that I would be a great fit and would try to set up the interview with the hiring director the following week. The hiring director leaves for extended travel and is not available.

It's been two weeks. And since then, I have been interviewed by several other places in person.

Is it appropriate for me to let the recruiter of this first company know about these interviews in hopes of expediting the processes?

Comment: Is the recruiter a company employee? Or external?

Comment: The recruiter is a company employee

Comment: You might find [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/2322) very relevant then - it is nearly exactly the situation you are describing.