# How long do companies wait for a candidate to decide if they accept an offer?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I've got one offer in place and I told the HR guy that I'd think about it and get back to him. The company seems good but the pay is a bit low. I'm also about to receive another offer from another company and unless it's good I'm planning to tell them that I will think about it as well.

For how long will companies typically 'wait' for me before giving up on me? A week? Two weeks?

Comment: At most about a week seems fair

Comment: This is individual to the company and the position. There is no one answer to this.

Comment: I removed your "Bonus Question" as such questions are not approriate here.  In reguards to that question I recommend you check out [THIS QUESTION](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/16) as if you asked your bonus question on its own it would likely be closed as a duplicate

Comment: They never tried to get you to agree to a decision date?

Answer (score 8):

The absolutely conclusive and definite answer to your question is:

> **It depends.**

It can depend on how much they like you, how urgently they need someone to start, how many other acceptable candidates they have, company policy, or a host of other things that vary from company to company.

If you are in this situation and need to know the answer in your case, **ask the company**.

Answer (score 1):

I *JUST* went through this in hiring for a position in my team.

Here are the variables:

- How desperate is the need to fill the position?  Are other people pulling overtime because the position is vacant?
- Are there other qualified candidates "next in line" if you're slow to respond?
- Do you bring a hard-to-find skill set necessary to the position with you, or are you another round peg for another round hole?

I actually hired someone who was more skilled, but had a later available start date than others because she was more skilled and experienced.  However, the role I needed to fill is fairly uncommon, so my choices were limited.

She starts next week, even though I could have hired the other guy starting a week ago.  I'm putting in extra hours to cover until she gets here, so employers are willing to wait if they need "You."  Just be sure you're not overvaluing yourself.