# How do you handle multiple offers?

Tags: job-offer

I'm a 39 year old graduate in BSc (Hons) Computing and have applied for multiple jobs and think I may get a few offers over the next week or so. What shall I do if I get multiple offers ? All 3 are great jobs, but I have my eye on one in particular. It's taken me a few months to get to this stage and now everything is looking much more positive.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: more detail please, but too "specific" of a story

Comment: Hi Catess76, welcome to The Workplace! As it stands, your question right now is unclear and is likely to be closed. We are looking for specific answerable questions and don't offer generic career advice. Check out or [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask questions and for a list of [what topics are on-topic here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Feel free to [edit your question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/55481/edit) to add more details to your question.

Comment: Jeez this place. It's the first time I've gone for technical jobs since my years of studying. It's been a bit of an experience in itself applying for technical roles. I'm not sure how I can extend my question. I'm not asking for CAREER advice I'm asking if anyone has been through this could share there opinion. Why the constant sarcasm on this site ? I'm looking forward to starting work on my chosen career anyway, hopefully very soon. Thanks.

Comment: @Catess76 It's not that we don't want to help, however the stack exchange site tries to keep questions as applicable to many people as possible, and we try to not ask duplicate questions. Some things you could do to better meet these guidelines (the ones I see here are that the question is a vague "What should I do" that would be better suited to people more familiar with your situation, and that it's not particularly applicable to anyone but you), would be to make it more generic. A good question title might be "How can I professionally handle multiple job offers?"....

Comment: ....Although that one in particular has probably been asked already. One of the great things about the SE network is that chances are someone has had a problem very similar to yours, and someone else has probably already answered it.

Comment: This question is also very similar: [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: I have tried to edit your question to improve it, but the problem I have is I don't really know what the question is. It might be "if I get an offer from my second choice, how can I stall them until I know if I'm getting one from my first choice?" It might be "how can I urge my first choice to make me an offer or disappoint me as soon as possible?" It might be "how can I stay calm with all this going on, it's so exciting I think I might actually get multiple job offers!" It could be **anything**. Please edit your question to make it clear what you're looking for **an answer to**.

Comment: amazing the amount of energy used in scrutinizing the question. Just don't respond if you can't help me.... no problemo. Looks like some people have had no problem in helping, that's fine. Thanks :-) Help or don't, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catess, since you've only put your applications in, I'd recommend not actively persuing one at the detriment of persuit of another. At this early stage, it's great to consider which jobs you'd prefer, but since you haven't been contacted for any of them, it'd be in your favor to make sure and be attentive and respond to all possibilities with equal enthusiasm. The ball will be in your court once you have job offers to compare, but until then, make sure and keep up with any communication and diplomacy with all three possible employers. One thing to keep in mind is in this situation, even an interview does not constitute an offer. Just because you've had an interview with your dream employer, don't skip out on contact with the others until you have the job secured.

Comment: Yes I will take that on board definitely , thanks Sidney.

Comment: Sorry this answer is seriously late - but thankyou for the advice :-) I am now in a job, also studying part time masters in Cyber Security and am excited about the future !

Comment: @Catess76 Congrats! Here's hoping for the best.

Answer (score 1):

@Catess76 - Hello! Job hunting is always a challenge and deciding upon one offer among multiple choice is more challenging today. But I'ts good to have a hard game as this decision means how good your decision making and analysing capabilities are.
Now, I faced the similar situation, I had two offers on  hand and I had to decide on one. My best choice was based on my requirements. A job decision doesn't means salary alone.This includes the commute,your stay,facilities, benefits,Future growth,technology and your ability of survival. Beyond everything, your heart will always look towards one choice which will always be the best to choose. So, decide and select your job after evaluating all the pros and cons thoroughly. But, make sure you decide quickly as the second offer shouldn't go away from your hand. The below link that I came across will be helpful for you to decide.

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-do-i-balance-a-job-offer-with-potential-offers/

I believe this article will be relatively helpful for you to decide upon. All the very best!

Comment: Yes i will need to weigh up all the factors of each job. Is it OK then if I get a job offer to maybe say "I am expecting to hear from a few other applications I have made recently, can I give you a decision in a few days or one I hear from them so I can make my decision", I'm scared if I say that they may withdraw there offer.... (if they offer !!!)

Answer (score 0):

> What shall I do if I get multiple offers ?

That would be a great position to be in!

- Make a list of the job factors that are important to you (salary, commute, opportunity for advancement, etc, etc)
- For each offer, rate the factor. For example, if you have 3 offers, then rate the each factor on a scale of 1 to 3 - 1 is the best, 2 is next best, 3 is the worst.
- Add up the ratings for each offer
- Choose the one with the lowest total and accept their offer
- Once the offer is final, decline the others, thanking them for their consideration
- Don't look back. Go out and kill it!

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's a great way to deal with the situation. I'll definitely use that system. Very grateful, thanks :-)