# Career Advice: Should I leave my current team or wait for promotion?

Tags: career-development, ethics, work-life-balance, politics, career-switch

I have been working for this company for about 11 months now. Everything is going well, however feel undervalued with regards to my salary.

About 4 months ago I was passed up for a position with a pay bracket I would have been happy with, and that I was qualified for. I then applied to an internal position outwith my current team. When my unit found out I was made an offer of promotion to stay, which I accepted.

Four months later I still don't have the promotion (as it has to be approved by agency). Present day, I was made an offer for an even better position in a different unit and am not sure if I can just leave my current position where I'm still waiting for a promotion.

Is leaving my current position unethical? Am I committing career suicide? I will still have to work with my old unit from time to time. The new position I have been offered greatly increase my personal life's goals.

Comment: "not on my unit" - but within the same company? I can't see that being career suicide, but it's more likely to depend on the culture in your company. However if it's a better position that you couldn't get in your current team then I'm sure your team will understand why you want to leave and take it.

Comment: I currently have an offer from my current unit (manager) so is it poor to walk away and take the gaurenteed one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa), though since it is all internal to your current job you can be much more up front and honest.

Comment: You applied for another position **seven months** after joining? That's generally just Not Done and many managers would have serious reservations about your commitment to the job. That said, it seems like you might be in a special situation if you've got two offers for other internal positions already.

Comment: Career advice (by your own admission) : off topic for the site,  voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

It's never unethical to switch careers because you don't think you're valued enough in your current position, especially if they haven't actually given you the promotion they promised.

Your current unit will be aware of your situation and that you're not happy with things as they currently stand so I can't imagine it would be a big surprise to them that you're interested in something new. Whether it's career suicide or not probably depends on how you handle leaving your current team but I can't see how moving to a different team within the same organisation will negatively impact your future career.

Comment: So the tricky scenario is the promotion they promised they claim is an institutional lag of time. Furthermore the promotion is just monetary and it pays less than the offer I was given by the other unit

Comment: I don't think it is tricky. The new offer seems to be better for you in every sense, so there's no reason you shouldn't go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Loyalty is never only to one party or ideal. Think of loyalty in terms of circles of trust. You should trust yourself above all others, then your most trustworthy associates (family, friends, colleagues, companies), then everyone else (other family, friends, colleagues, companies). Only distrust those who have proven or demonstrated that they are unreliable.

So, be loyal to yourself first. This new position advances you as a person. Your most trustworthy associates will not only understand your choice to take the new position, but will be glad for you. If any of them is dismayed that you take it, or even disapprove, consider moving them into the next circle of trust further out, but only until you can build the strength of trust that you thought you shared with them. Don't ever neglect building trust.

Comment: When you say be loyal to yourself "first," do you mean putting yourself first or considering how it impacts you first? Because if you just consider what is best for you first, what is the point in considering the rest of the team. Not trying to be too literal or linear; just wanted to clarify your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely with kirstyannelouise on this one.  I would suggest that you explain this in a positive light, though.  The reason that you are taking the other position is that you feel that you can make a better and more meaningful contribution to the company by taking this position, as it more fully leverages the skills and experience that you have to contribute.

It's important to remember that positions that are better for you are better in part because they allow you to do more for the company.  If you focus on how you can improve the contribution that you make, rather than how you can advance yourself, you'll find that the advancement takes place naturally.  (If you don't find that, then find a company where it does.)

Answer (score 0):

Most people take jobs and within certain teams are doing so based on what is best for them and will take the opportunity to go for something better.

There's nothing about your situation that indicates anything different, but if you persuaded, or encouraged the other people to join this team under false pretenses, like you knew you weren't going to stick it out because of not getting the promotion you expected, you would have to deal with the moral dilemma and the consequences of lying to and abandoning the team.

There may not be any negative. How would we know? If there is a chance of any of your current team members being promoted over you, there could be some regrets.