# Was waiting for an offer from X company, mean time got an interview call from Y company . In Dilemma please Help

Tags: interviewing, negotiation

I had been interviewed by an X company and I was really lucky to reach the HR round. After few negotiations in HR round the salary was finalised and they were ready to give my preferred Location Bangalore. I asked them when can I expect the offer letter?. Their answer was in a week.

I was waiting like mad and continuously checking my email, mean time I thought of updating my naukri profile with "servicing notice period" and mentioned the company name and salary they offered.

Now that my profile is updated with having an offer, I was getting many more calls comparitively and for all I used to tell the same thing that I have an offer from X company.

But unfortunately after all the discussion in HR round , I donno what would have been the lame reason but I got a regret mail from X company.

But by now I have let other companies know that I have an offer from this X company and may be that's the reason they had shortlisted me and scheduled an interview next week.

Now I am in dilemma as to what should I tell them if they ask me to provide an offer letter from X company. It looks like I am cheating with Y Company but I am not . It was my bad luck .

Please help me what to do further? Should I reject the interview call by telling that I don't have any offer by now ? Or what am I supposed to do ??? I am in Complete dilemma state not able to prepare for interviews also. Please guide me.

Comment: Just tell them it is a verbal offer and you are available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: "Now I am in dilemma as to what should I tell them if they ask me to provide an offer letter from X" - It sounds like you are imagining problems before they have come up. If someone does ask, you can just say the offer didn't come to fruition. Next time, don't publicly announce your offer status; things like these happen.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you made the mistake of "putting the cart before the horse", "counting your chickens before they hatched", and "doubling-down on an eight". In other words, you should **never** treat anything verbal as a guarantee. Until you have the written offer letter in hand, you should operate under the premise that **anything** could happen and that offer doesn't exist.

It is unlikely that any prospective employer will ask you to provide an actual offer letter as a condition of hire. However, if they do ask you about the offer--and **ONLY** if they ask--simply say that the offer was verbal, you haven't received anything concrete from them, and enough time has passed that if you actually were to receive something from them now, you would most likely decline.

In the future, I would suggest you only communicate your job status when you actually have the job.