# I have two job offers - one verbal and one written

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources

I'm in a bit of sticky situation. But I'll try my best to explain.

Let's call company A - the one I really want to work for and company B - my backup choice.

Back in April, I was let go from my previous job. I left a company I was working for 3 years to pursue new opportunities. After 7 mo of working, my position was eliminated after re-structuring the department I was working in.

**My available  date isn't until mid July due to personal reasons.**

After searching for my next opportunities in May

- May 22 - 1st interview with Comp A
- May 29 - Skype interview with Comp B
- June 3 - In-person interview with Comp B
- June 7 - 2nd interview with Comp A
- June 8 - 3rd interview + Job shadowing with Comp B
- June 9 - Comp B verbally offered me a job and asked me to make my decision by Tuesday - but I asked them to send me the written offer letter before I decide on anything.
- June 12 - I called Comp A and let them know that they are my 1st choice but I have a verbal job offer from somewhere else. The manager of the position called me back 2 hrs later. The manager told me that they believe 
  I'm the right candidate and strongly expressed their interest in hiring me. He also said if everything goes how he wants, he will call me back on Wednesday with the offer.
- June 13 - Comp B called and told me that there is a delay in written offer due to General Manger being on holidays.
- June 14 - Comp A called and told me that I am the chosen candidate for the position - They apologies for not having the written offer - but HR will send me the written offer by Friday and the manager informed me that he's going on holidays until the following week.
- June 15 - I called Comp A HR and asked details of the offer. She gave me further information on my salary, vacation, stats holidays, retirement plans, benefits, etc. again she apologized that "it so happened to be a bad timing atm because all the new positions need to be approved by HR headquarters. She said she put my job offer as a "critical" as the candidate has another offer. She said written offer is ready, but can't send it to me until the HQ approves and the latest update she has is 'HQ said they will approve by end of the day so it can be sent the next day (Friday)'
- June 16th Friday - no written offer from both companies
- June 19th Monday - received a written offer from Comp B and I sent a follow up email to Comp A.

The Comp A is a big organization with many deparments and the department that I'd be placed in has their own HR. I talked to the HR manager and she informed me that the offer isnt approved from HQ to be sent out yet. And because of the 2/4 quarters and the HQ is reviewing all the new positions, she said it's taking a lot longer. She also told me that the manager of my position is on holidays and even he's constantly checking in wih her to see if my offer approved. The position is needed for this company and she informed me if it disapproves, they have a back up plan for it to be approved. Moreover she said I'd be the first person for them to contact as soon as she hears anything back from the HQ and she'll contact the HQ again to see what the hold up is and if there is any chance of the position being disapproved. She said shemd let me know yesterday but I have not heard anything back...

I am probably over thinking and I'm worried about for whatever reason, the Comp A HQ will disapprove and the offer will be job rescinded. Logically, I understand the bigger the company, HR process takes a lot longer especially if it needs to be approved by the HQ. I have until this Friday to get back to Comp B (and they raised the salary by 5k than the original offer - but Comp A offers more and there is no commute).

I'm thinking I would wait few more days (until Thursday) and give Comp A a call if there is no further update on the approval process. If they assure me that it's coming and I have the job (which they did...) again - I'm thinking to decline the offer from Comp B.

The industry I'm in is very small and connected. I want to take the job at Comp B and accept when Comp A sends one later - However, because the industry is small, I don't want to burn bridges..

Any suggestion? am I overthinking the situation?  Any thoughts appreciated.

TLDR - Two job offers - one verbal (written offer in a process of being approved by its head quarter) and one written. Stressed out because I want to work for the company that offered me the job verbally. However, written offer is taking longer than anticipated.

UPDATE: I decided to decline the offer from Company B morning of Friday. Then, Friday evening, Company A called to let me know that the position approved by the upper mansgement and they officially offered me the job!

Comment: Verbal offer = no offer.  They haven't promised to do anything.  That's just how I look at it.

Comment: A bird in the hand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: The pay may not matter as much as you think if you get "enough".

Comment: What you really have is an offer and a conversation.  Conversations are nice, but they don't pay the bills.

Answer (score 11):

You don't have 2 offers, you have 1 offer  and someone trying to get approval for another.  In reality there are a hundred reasons this can fall through.

You've already told them you have another offer pending.  Are there enough good things about company A to risk losing the offer you do have?  That's up to you.

Comment: I guess I count a verball offer as an offer. I just dont want to take the offer from comp B and Comp A coming to me with a written offer.. then I have to reject Comp B after I already taken their offer... thanks for your input

Comment: That's the mistake.  All it takes is to have someone else submit a new hire request 5 minutes before your contact and the budget for your position is gone.  A verbal offer is worth the paper it's written on, nothing more.

Comment: You do not HAVE to reject B if you get an offer from A.  You might find the time and money investment in your commute too much to be worth the additional pay.

Comment: Comp A with verball offer pays more money and there would be no commute. I guess if I dont hear anything back, Id have to take the offer from B tomorrow.

Comment: @JeffreyPark You don't have a verbal offer. An offer is something you can accept and taken action on. The only way you would have a verbal offer is if it were made by someone with the authority to make that offer and that hasn't happened.  *Even then* it would be worthless until you actually sign something. *And even then* they can be rescinded before you actually start work.  All you have is someone trying to delay you from taking action. No offer.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep - In this case, it is true that I do have a verbal offer. The director of the department called me on Jun 14 that the job offer letter will be coming to my way. The HR has the offer letter written and ready to be sent, except the company is reviewing all the new positions, which (my position) is still being reviewed. This is why it's very difficult for me to make the decision to accept the offer from Comp B. There is still a chance that it may be disapproved but very unlikely Comp A said. But nothing is 100% certain until the written offer is sent to me and signed.

Comment: @JeffreyPark, promises are made on paper, wishful thinking is done with words.  Until you get a piece of paper with an offer, you have nothing.  Consider Company A's manager and what he said - *....if everything goes how he wants, he will call me back on Wednesday with the offer.*  Did he have the offer?  No.  Think about it - he either lied to you, knowing that HQ HR must approve all offers and that that wasn't going to happen by wednesday, or, he thought he knew the process enough to get it through and got smacked down by some higher up.  Either way, this proves the value of his promises.

Comment: @Prinz I didn't think that was his promise by him saying if everything goes how he wants.

Comment: @JeffreyPark, if the Company A manager had said instead: *"I can't give you an offer until I hear back from HQ HR and I don't know how long that will take"* -- would you still be conflicted as to what to do?  If so, then it is clear that your desire for Company A is so strong that nothing Company B can do will convince you to go with them.  i.e. the two in the bush are worth more to you than the one in the hand.

Comment: @Prinz He did say that. You're right. I guess I'm seeking for an answer that I already know. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3):

Overthinking it?  Possibly.  I think it's natural to be concerned, especially since Comp A is the company you want to work for.  However, as long as they have not gotten a full written offer, in reality, you have no guarantee of a job there.  A verbal offer of a job is interesting, but it doesn't give any legal guarantee that you will get it.  If you're applying to a very small company, there's very good chances of you getting the job, but even at that, there's no guarantee.

For me, the situation you basically have is: 1 job offer (Comp B) and 1 person who's interested in hiring you (Comp A).

Exactly what should you do?  It's up to you.  You run a risk of losing both jobs if you wait for Comp A to come through.  On the other hand, you might get it.  It's a bargain, and you have to determine *yourself* whether it's worth running the risk of losing both jobs by turning down Comp B.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask Comp B for an extension?  The worst they can do is refuse and demand a final answer as scheduled.

"I'm in the middle of considering your offer, and I'd appreciate a few extra days on the offer deadline.  If it doesn't cause a big problem, may I give you my answer no later than COB next Wednesday, 29 June?"

Comment: the last thing I want to do is inconvenient their hiring process due to my selfishness.