# Balancing two jobs

Tags: job-search, canada, part-time, scheduling

I'm a high-schooler in Ontario and I currently work part-time 1 day/wk at an educational service for kids. They have set my time slot to Monday, though I could ask for it to be moved.

I've applied for two jobs in the restaurant industry. I am "in training" at both of them but haven't gotten formal job offers from either. I only plan to stick with one once I get real offers.

While I'm in training and once I choose one of the jobs, how do I make sure that my two jobs don't conflict? How do I explain myself when an employer wants me to cover a certain day but it has been taken already by the other?

Comment: I made some pretty drastic edits to remove extra info and bring your question more on topic. I removed your question about which job to choose, as [we can't make a decision for you](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695), and we already have a good question about [how to manage multiple applications](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa). Feel free to [edit] your question if you want to make any changes, and welcome to The Workplace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you have a consistent work day for your first job, be upfront to your other employer(s) that you cannot work Mondays (or whatever day) due to your other job.

If you are asked to cover a shift on that particular day you can reply:

> Sorry, I work Mondays at the educational services for kids but happy to help out where I can. Need me to cover someone else's shift on another day?

Having multiple jobs in the restaurant industry is very common and employers are used to these types of conflicts. Be upfront, honest, and willing to be a team player the best you can.

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen when I was in high school. I just told my second job that I am not available Monday - Wednesday and my second job was able to schedule around that just fine. People understand that often times an individual has to work two (or more) jobs to make ends meet and will work around that. So be honest and communicate.