# Updating Resume/LinkedIn to show that you have an offer after internship?

Tags: resume, applications, linkedin

**Background**: I'm a college senior who recently was offered a full time position at a fortune 100 company when I graduate after completing a summer internship this summer but am still applying to other jobs in hopes of something better before the offer expires.

**Question**: Something I've seen some people do after receiving a full time offer after an internship is to update their LinkedIn and Resume to show that they were given a full time offer after a successful internship.

On one hand I think that it attests to the fact that you are a proven quantity and clearly were successful in the internship and valued. On the other hand I can see why some companies would find it to be a negative given that it raises the likelihood that a candidate would reject their offer or be more likely to negotiate.

Should I update my application materials to reflect that or keep this fact under wraps?

Comment: so did you actually go through an internship in that company? Or you are *yet* to take it?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I completed a summer internship last summer (summer 2017) and was given a full time offer for the company that I interned at.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @Dukeling that first possible duplicate I doubt, as the offer is not for sure to be considered "future employment". However, the second link does seem like a dupe

Comment: See also [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111) If you get to the stage of having a conversation with someone, you should mention the other offer (if you need them to speed up their process, otherwise there's little point to mentioning it unless explicitly asked), but keep it off your resume. Starting the process with another company if you already have an offer seems unlikely to give them enough time though. When's the deadline on accepting the offer?

Comment: They've given me an extended deadline so I have until the end of October.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I update my application materials to reflect that or keep this fact under wraps?

You should include the job experiences you **actually had**, not those that were a possibility or prospect.

Including things that you **did not** do could harm the way interviewers see you as a candidate, as adding those jobs you did not take can be perceived as you trying to make your resume seem longer/better than it actually is.

In any case, you should include the internship you had, as that is actually a valid and *real* (verifiable) job experience you had.

If you are really proud of the offer they made you, and you think it can be a vantage point on some job you are after, you could *try* mentioning it during the **interview** if the subjects comes along, but not in your resume or similar material. Anyways, you are free to add it to your materials if you cant help it. Hope this helps.