# I received a job offer while I'm waiting to hear back from a preferred employer

Tags: job-offer, job-change, italy

About 10 days ago I had a job interview and since then I didn't receive any news. The hiring manager told me that he would interview other candidates and let me know within a week. I was impressed by this company and I think I will have no doubt accepting their possible job offer.

In the meantime, I received a job offer from another company and I should give them a feedback in a couple of days. I'm more interested with the other opportunity, what should I do? Should I ask them for news or it is too early?

Comment: One in the hand is worth two in the bush.

Comment: Has it been a week yet?

Comment: Yes, 10 days now

Comment: tell your preferred company you have a job offer, and you need to respond by <whenever you need to respond by>. it doesn't matter if it has been one day or 10, if they want you they will get back to you asap

Comment: Hi there's a similar question to this [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa) do any of the answers there help you at all?

Comment: @bharal that would be a good answer.  Why don't you copy and paste it below and get credit for it?

Answer (score -1):

I would send a brief and polite follow up email to the preferred employer since it has been longer than the estimated response date.  Hopefully they get back to you before you need to respond to the other job offer.

You could also let the preferred company know that you have other job offers that you need to get back to, which might force them to respond quickly if they truly want you to work for them.