# How to pace job-application process in great job market?

Tags: hiring-process, applications, europe

Currently, the job market for anything coding or data related is really great in the Netherlands.
I have had two interviews, both were for places I would like to work and I have a short list of 4 other applications to write.
How should I pace my interviews so that I can make a good decision when I decide which job to take?

For example, this weekend I still have to do an online assessment for one of the interviews, look for my diploma, and I want to write at least 2 cover letters (so I have 2 of the 4 remaining applications done). Which one should I prioritize: assessment or cover letters?

Should I aim at getting applications to synchronize, so postpone assessment/second interview or should I run with one and then if they want me, tell them to give me 2 weeks to decide?

I am also considering letting recruiters in, because what if they could find me that great job that was also within cycling distance! But I'm weary because their phone-calls tend to take a lot of time.

Edit: [this is a very similar question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa), however, I haven't had any offers yet, so I can maybe slow down the application process a little at this stage so my other applications 'catch up'.

Comment: @gnat I don't think so. This question does not involve job offers. Ivana probably wants to apply in a way that will allow multiple offers to coincide (i.e. fall within a few days of each other).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to over-engineer the process. If you proceed at a normal pace, you will likely receive a job offer. Once you have an offer in hand, that will spur the other companies to make decisions more quickly.

If you try to draw out or delay the process, the companies you're interviewing with may read that as a lack of interest, and look less favorably on your application.