# Should I be transparent with job offer deadlines to all recruiters?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, job-acceptance

I initially received a job offer from Company A on Monday and they told me they wanted a response to their offer by Thursday.

I relayed this information to the recruiters from Company B, C and D. I told them that I have an offer on the table and I needed to address it by Thursday. This prompted B to send an offer Wednesday while C and D told me on Wednesday that they would make an offer Thursday.

Company A called me Thursday morning and I explained the situation of receiving multiple offers, some of which required relocation. A said I could have until Monday to respond to their offer.

*Should I let the recruiters from the other companies know I have additional time to respond to Company A's job offer?* While it is the truth, I don't want them to think I might have been lying / strong arming them into an offer. Also, if it makes a difference, these job offers are for software engineering.

Comment: Related question: [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/16)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I let the recruiters from the other companies know I have additional time to respond to Company A's job offer?

*They already said they will make their offers on Thursday*, so they should be preparing their offers and you should expect them by that day; I don't see what you would get by telling them company A gave *you* more time.

Stepping a bit back from your question, I also think you should be *focusing your effort/time in deciding among the offers you already have* (companies A and B), and do the same with C and D as soon as you get the offer.

All in all, I think you managed to coordinate these offers in a good way, assuming C and D respond Thursday (today, I take it) you will have your 4 offers lined up and be ready to decide. Good luck with the rest of the process.

Comment: Should I assume that Company B, C, D are expecting a response by the end of Thursday (today)? Would it be unwise to ask for some time to consider their offer ?

Comment: @krikara Company B should have stated when they expect an answer when they gave you their offer (as company A did by asking your answer by Monday). The same will/should happen when C and D give you their offers, they should come with an expected date for you to answer.