# Thinking about accepting a previous declined offer

Tags: job-offer, job-change

Back in December, I had two interviews and eventually received an offer with good working conditions (more salary then where I'm employed now). I decided to decline the offer because I felt I wouldn't fit in the team. I'm quite young and the people I'd have to work with are 20+ years older than me and all of a different gender.

Sadly, I am not able to find other jobs and I start to think that my initial decline was maybe a bit rash and taken too quickly. I want to leave my current employment because of poor payment and no room for growth. I still think it would be hard for me to fit in the team, but I will at least be able to learn and develop myself more than my current job.

Should (and if how) I reach out to the company again and ask if the job is still available? (according to Indeed it is) Or should I stick with my previous reasons and leave it in the past and hope another job will come around soon?

Comment: Think twice. If you had refused the _only_ oppertunity you had at that time, you must have had a very good , strong and compelling reason, given that you were actively looking. Now, none of the conditions because of which you refused, seem to have changed - so how are you going to adjust?

Comment: Does this help: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155368/how-can-i-get-a-potential-employer-to-reissue-an-offer-i-rejected/155378#155378 ?

Comment: I do not think your reasons are very compelling, but then, you were there and I was not. Anyway, in the current COVID-19 situation, is changing jobs really an option?

Comment: what do you mean "in the current COVID-19 situation is changing jobs really an option"?

Answer (score 1):

I would directly contact the previous company and ask if the offer is still open.

You will need to explain to the company why the previous problems with the job are now no longer problems.  Explain why you accepting a job will be good for the company and good for yourself.

Be positive
stick to the facts

If you can keep improving your skills, knowledge and experience then you will get more exciting job offers in the future and you will be more valuable to a company.  The more value you bring the more pay you get.