# Is it okay to call a recruiter to speed up the process?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment, applications

So I have been contacted on LinkedIn by a recruiter for an open position of his client. After the first calls, I've decided to apply for that position and sent him my CV, I also got positive feedback that the potential company wants a first interview with me. So far, so good.

Now the recruiter is contacting the company to schedule a time for an interview, however, weeks have passed without any proceeding forward. I have emailed the (3rd party) recruiter a week ago asking for the status, and he told me that he has been very busy and could not schedule a time yet. Now another week has passed again.

Is it okay to call and ask for them to hurry up? I have another application process nearing the end, and it would be rude to let them wait for too long. At the same time I don't want to quit the application process with the recruiter before the very first interview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat I think that is a different situation, since I have no direct contact to the company in my case. Communication was all via the external recruiter. And my process is already stuck at scheduling the interview, I did not even had the chance to present myself to the company apart from the CV

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111)

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you must. Nothing waits forever.

If the recruiter said they are *busy with priorities*, that can mostly mean two (or three) things:

- The advertised position is no longer available, and the recruiter is trying to see if a similar one opens up in the same organization or other.
- They simply did not have an actual opening, that communication was just to take your info and then try finding something that matches up your resume.
- They have better paying jobs, for which the commission / payout will be higher and to ensure those process runs smooth, your application is taking a backseat.

Either way, they are stalling you (which would be bad for them also, should they had an actual job opening) - call them up and ask for a date for interview. Nothing good can come for you by waiting for them to get back without a defined deadline.

Also, make progress with other offers if you have them. Do not bank upon this one only (unless that's the only option you've got).

Comment: Yes, no point waiting

Comment: Note that in _any of these cases_, I'd tend not to continue business with that recruiter.