# How long can I leave it before accepting or declining a job offer?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, internship

I just got an offer for a year long internship and I'm very excited about it but I want to be smart about this as I am also mid-way through the application process with a couple other companies.

The issue is I have no clue if/when the other companies will offer me a job. What is the standard practice for this situation? How long can I leave it before responding? Is there any risk that if I don't reply quick enough the offer will be revoked? (I have the weekend at least to think about it). Can I tell them I want to wait for other companies to respond?

Comment: Has the company indicated a date by which they need your response?

Comment: @sf02 No unfortunately not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: @gnat yes, brilliant thank-you for the link

Comment: How long would you wait for a company to say final yes or no on you wanting to work with them?

Comment: Is there any room for negotiation which may have you win some days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the standard practice for this situation? How long can I leave it before responding?

Typically, if the company did not explicitly give you a date, you should give them an answer within one week.  Any longer and the company will assume you are not serious about the position.

> Is there any risk that if I don't reply quick enough the offer will be revoked? (I have the weekend at least to think about it).

The longer you wait, the more time the company has to consider other candidates.  Even though they made an offer to you they will likely have a plan B and if you were narrowly chosen, hesitation on your part could sway the decision.

> Can I tell them I want to wait for other companies to respond?

This will likely do more harm than good.  Some companies would assume you are either not serious about accepting their offer or are simply attempting to use either their offer or another company's offer as leverage for increased salary/benefits/etc.