# Job offer via email, but not recruited yet due to the secuirty clearance issues

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, security-clearance

I have been offered a job by a employer, but due to security check issues I have not been recruited yet. They have not even sent me a contract and discussed the salary. The position is kind of security sensitive and they have asked me for a few clearance documents so far. I have accepted the offer via email but that's it. They have put me on hold for 1.5 months now. Now, my question is that professionally speaking, can I do interviews with other employers and dump the previous position once I am offered a job which hire me immediately?

I think they are in the last steps of this security check, but I don't really liked the fact that they didn't even discuss salary or gave me a preview of the contract. I'm desperate to find a job in this pandemic,  I didn't want to bring any tension into the table....

Comment: You don't stop interviewing until you (and they) have a signed contract. Being "offered a job" means they have placed a signed contract in front of you.

Comment: Also, why would you accept without knowing the salary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: Just want to make sure this a real, reputable company. Turning over potentially secure documents without much communication for 1.5 months and without talking about salary/offer sounds very fishy.

But, yes, you should still be looking!!! Apparently this place is contingent on the background check, but 1.5mos is generally unacceptable. It it takes them this long, imagine what the experience working there might be like.

Comment: Never accept an offer only. Next time, ask for the contract before you accept. And yes, contracts can have escape clauses that say "Pending the successful completion of a background check/security clearance check."

Comment: @Gregory Currie  because i really need a job and based on the position and similar salary evaluation on Glassdoor i could say their salary would satisfy me anyway.

Comment: @Austin759, thanks for mentioning these concerns. This is a position from goverment, so everything is verified and there is no scamming going on. The job just requires major secuirty checks. And yea I know, they were not really handling this professionally but ive been unemployed for months and this position looks shiny to me no matter what. F* covid

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. You were really helpful.

Comment: @aaa I get that, but because you accepted without even knowing the salary they know you're desperate. Which may be one reason why they are jerking you around. I really suggest you keep looking while you wait for them to get back to you.

Comment: Are they paying you? If not, keep looking

Comment: My nephew was in the same position. Formally accepted in May 2020, security cleared in december 2020, begain in February 2021. He did 2 small contracts in the meantime. Tilmes are hard. Hence the answer : don't stop looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, my question is that professionally speaking, can I do interviews with other employers and dump the previous position once I am offered a job which hire me immediately?

Yes. They have made no real commitment to you, so you are not obliged to keep waiting for them. If any, putting you on a 6 week hold is rather unprofessional.

Given that's a government entity the 6 weeks may easily turn into 3 or 6 months, so by all means keep on looking. If you find something better, you should give them "first right of refusal". Let them know that you have an alternative, waiting is no longer an option and ask them if they are willing to move their time line if they are still interested. For most government agencies it won't do any good, but it's the polite thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

If any company gives you a written job offer with full details including pay, and benefits, but still has conditions such as passing a background check, receiving approval from the customer, or awarding of a contract; then you are not obligated to stop looking. As long as there are conditions, then there is a chance you won't get the job.

In your case they haven't even told you the salary, or benefits, or other key information. That gives you even less reason to feel loyalty to them. You could find out in a month that they are only going to pay you 80% of your minimum acceptable salary. If that happens it could take weeks or months to get another offer.

So keep applying, keep interviewing, and keep negotiating.