# A company offered me a job, can I tell them I'll ask others before accepting?

Tags: professionalism, communication, ethics

This coming summer, I will graduate from a school in my country (Italy) where I did 2 years of classes and internship. I didn't like the company where I interned the first year (company A). Last summer, I started a project with another company (company B), and asked the school to continue the internship in this company.

Company B was not eager to hire me initially, but I was more interested in the project, and in what I would learn, than in the job itself.

After a year of internship, they are very happy with me, and they asked me to stay (we haven't discussed the details yet). It would be great for me because I like the company, I like the colleagues, I would be autonomous, and work with IoT.

The thing is that, for a year I've been looking for companies I would like to apply for, because I was not sure that I would have been hired, and I have a list of them right now (let's call them C). I'd like to send my CV and letters to them and see what they say.

There is a probability that C won't even consider me, but if they ask me for an interview I would like to do it.

Shortly, I will look for an interview from C while I already more or less have an offer from B.

Can I tell this to company B? Is it more correct to inform them, or is it too risky?
I could gain more negotiation power with other offers, but I think that, if I tell them, they would be offended and withdraw the offer.

Why would you ask others for an interview when you already have an offer for a job that you like?

Mainly, I'm just curious, but I'm also uncertain because in B I would be the only one that will work on IoT, and I'm pretty new to it. I do have some experience, but without a guide, using "personal" solutions that are not standard or optimized.

If I get a job in C I could learn how professionals work, instead of just making up something to solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: "I could gain more negotiation power" — perhaps, generally; also, some people somehow are better suited to pull this off, some may be less. It also depends on your personality, confidence, and negotiating _talent_. If you don't feel confident to have picked up negotiation talent in your family background (parents?), then you better consider your current position: a (promising?) beginner, straight out of school. _How much power can you have_? How much _should_ you have? You may encounter people who feel you shouldn't, and you might be cheap enough to let go even on this principle alone...

Comment: I'm not discouraging you, and not saying any of this would happen. All I suggest is adding these considerations into the equation.

Comment: Thank you gnat, it helps, but i feel the situation a bit different, I still have to send something to C ( and i'm also considering not to do it, at this point).

Comment: Joe, I probably have enough time to send some letters to other before B makes an official offer, my doubt was about being 100% honest with them or just telling I have to evaluate other offers. Levente, I see your point, I'm not going to ask more than i think I deserve, I could be an important figure in B and having other offers could just help negotiating. Thank you for your reply guys

Comment: ciao Guilio, my gut instinct - B is better for your career.  IoT is an incredible field, I wish I was in your age/position!  Don't forget in software/related **you have to figure everything out for yourself**.   The idea that in "C" you would get mentorship/guidance ........... is a myth I'm afraid.  Enjoy!

Comment: Ciao! This make me feel both relieved and put off ahah i'm not that young anymore but thank you, I'm taking this seriously

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can I tell this to company B?

You can, but it's not in your interest to do so. It needlessly damages your reputation, which matters if you do end up signing with B (or wanting to sign with B but they have rescinded the offer).

Instead, stick to a "need to know" basis. Tell them you need some time to think on it. What you do in your personal time, whether you talk to C or not, is not something B needs to know.

Don't sell your eggs for cheap, because none of the companies you interact with will ever offer you something that's not in their own interest. Don't take a friendly face of an interviewer as comfort that you can share your inner thought process, because it will be used against you in the company's favor when possible.

Comment: As i thought, thank you. This is exactly what I ment with "risky". Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

As of now you don't have a written offer from B. You also don't even have an interview with C.

Until things change don't worry about what you have to tell B. They know that you should be looking.

Start by applying to C, D , E, F...

Take any interviews, and work on jumping though the hoops need to get to written unconditional offers from one of more of these companies.

Keep applying. Keep interviewing.

At some point you hope B will make an offer. Until that offer is unconditional you can keep moving the decision point down the road.

You do have one thing in your favor. You feel that there is a good chance the B will make you an offer. Accepting it and then leaving a few months later isn't a crime. So start looking and keep looking.

You don't have to tell B about the status of your job search.

Comment: "Start by applying to C, D , E, F..." and continue till you reach " ... X, Y, Z...". Then repeat applying from A to Z all over again till you get the official job offer letter from a company that you really like. Best of luck. :-)

Comment: I agree, mhoran, the point is that I have no time for interviews before they'll make the offer and if I want to ask them for time before deciding i'll have to justify. I'm going to try anyway (as i said, i'm not sure someone will ever answer), but my doubt was about how to behave with B, I usually think "honesty always pay" but in this situation is probably better not to be too specific. Thank you Joe_September, really!