# How can I accept offer and keep looking for new one?

Tags: interviewing, relocation

In recent months I accepted job as Software Developer which included relocation and change of my primary tech stack.

Unfortunately the company decided to withdraw offer when I was already relocated, due to economic situation.

I decided to search for new job in new tech stack, but I got significantly less replies than few months ago.

I successfully interviewed in one company, where I admitted to my current private life Situation.  I received offer, but it is lower from the one we originally agreed on, and later the company decided to change contract type, which makes it even less attractive.

Given it all, I'm not happy with the offer, but I'm still thinking about accepting it. I believe new company tries to low ball me, because they know my situation.

I believe I have two choices:

1. Suck it up, and accept the offer.
2. Accept the offer and still look around.

Second option is preferred one, but I don't know what I could tell to my potential future recruiters why I want to change job this time.

I'm thinking about hiding the fact that I have a new job but it would be unprofessional.

Do you have any advice how to present my situation during interview?

Comment: 3. Would be my preferred one, if I had my previous one. Unfortunately at the moment I'm jobless and I have significantly less replies for job positions, where I don't have experience in the given tech stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: @gnat I feel this is different because they are no other potential offers yet. There is no "Company C" from that question

Comment: Right now, there have been a large number of people accepting jobs and then, not showing up. There are people who have accepted a job, started working, and then, disappearing. It would be more professional to accept, keep looking, and then, give notice when finding something better.

Comment: At the moment there is no company B or C

Comment: Did the company offer to pay for your relocation? If so there is a good chance that they still owe you that payment, and that a good lawyer can easily persuade them to pay it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe new company tries to low ball me, because they know my situation.

That appears to be correct. I would do one more attempt in stating clearly "my goal is to have <insert_contract_type> at a compensation of <insert_target_salary>. Is  there a credible way we can achieve this goal right now or in the very near future?" Chances are they will stick with "no. take it or leave it".

If that's the case I think it's ok to accept the job (if you must) and keep looking. You have clearly expressed would you need for the job to be long term sustainable. If they ignore this, they know that they are low-balling you and that this is not a going to be a long term thing.

If you are interviewing for new jobs, just tell the truth.

1. You got relocated for a good offer but that fell through
2. That left you in a bind and you had to get something quickly to pay the bills
3. You clearly communicated what you need to the second employer to be long term sustainable but they didn't go for it/
4. If prospective employer can meet your goals, life will be great.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked: you do this by accepting the offer, turning up to your new job and continuing to look for other offers outside your working hours.

The first more nuanced question is "should you do this?" That's really only a decision you can make - but understand that you will almost certainly irreparably burn any bridges with your new employer. Only you can weigh up the cost of that against how much you need money today and/or your ability to get temporary work to tide you over.

The second more nuanced question is "how should you present this?" As often in this sort of case, the best option is probably the truth - but not the whole truth. "The new role isn't quite what I expected it to be, so I'm looking for something more aligned with my career goals" or similar.