# How to respond to a written offer when we have a verbal offer from a better-fit company?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, international

My spouse and I live in the U.S., and she has been out of work for about a month.  She has a written offer from Company A and a verbal offer from Company B.  She has negotiated and accepted the verbal offer from Company B, but Company A has given her a short deadline (not quite an exploding offer) to accept their written offer.

Company A had several possible red flags, such as a very short hiring process (less than 2 weeks to have 3-4 interviews and an expected response on a written offer) and a very understaffed team.  In their industry, layoffs are also common.  Company B seems like a much better fit based on their team culture, a more realistic workload, more interesting projects, probably much better job security, and a salary that is not as high as Company A’s but still comparable.  The start dates in the verbal offer is only 1 week after the start date in the written offer (within the same month), and that difference is manageable for us.

She is still waiting for a background check from Company B.  There could be delays with this because she has lived and worked in several different countries.  We still fully intend to have her accept Company B’s written offer once she receives it.

Could anyone who has navigated similar situations before advise us on **how** my spouse should respond to Company A, and **why**?

Comment: Come up with a question that requires them to take some time to answer that forces them to push their deadline. The things that work vary by situation.

Comment: How having a 2 week interview process, and an expected response on a written offer is red flag? Requirements for immediate joining is not very uncommon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: @gnat I did look at that question and its responses, but it does seem too generalized for our case.  She's done interviewing, but she was told to respond to Company A by today while her background check for Company B will take a few more days due to the overseas work experience.

Comment: "Thank you for your offer. I've decided to pursue a different opportunity." - Done.

Answer (score 2):

> How to respond to a written offer when we have a verbal offer from a better-fit company?

Typically, when presented with multiple offers you should accept the best offer ( based on your personal criteria ) and decline any other offers and thank those companies for their time.

In this case, your spouse has already accepted an offer from company B.  Even though it is a verbal offer, the fact that it holds sufficient weight to warrant a background check indicates that your spouse will very likely receive a written offer assuming all goes well with the background check.

The most professional response to company A would be to decline their offer and thank them for their time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

These would be my steps:

1. Contact Company B by phone and explain that you would really like their offer and want to accept, but you need it in writing, to be safe. If they are only waiting for background check, and you don't have any corpses in your basement (It's very likely the check will succeed), you can suggest they give you a written offer reserving the right to back out if the background check fails.
2. If Step 1 fails or needs too long, try to buy some time at Company A. Ask questions, start to negotiate (if not already done).
3. As a last resort, tell them you have another offer and you need x amount of days to consider both. This is not ideal, as it sends the signal "I would like another job better", but it's better than accepting the offer and stepping back from it some weeks later. There is the possibility that they tell you No. Now you need to make the decision if Company B is worth the risk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different take on things.  You don't decline a written offer for a verbal one.

Any company worth their salt understands that a written offer has concrete legal standing in the case that the company decides to reneg after making the offer.  A potential employee can sue for damages when this happens.  It'd be immensely harder to recover damages with only a verbal offer, and I guarantee you that the folks at Company B know this.

If I were your spouse, I'd refuse to do anything further with Company B until provided with a written offer.  If the company's truly interested, then this won't be a problem.  On the other hand, they might be "fishing" among several applicants with multiple verbal offers for the same job right now, which won't turn out so well for whoever they decide to throw back.

Answer (score -1):

If your contract with Company A has a quick termination clause, like quitting on the spot without any reason within a certain time frame (in Europe we have something called probation period), your wife could easily take the offer from Company A, work for a few weeks until the background check is done, then quit and accept the offer from Company B. Assuming she will like the offer they make.