# How much stalling is acceptable and fair when deciding between two jobs?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, australia

I'm looking for a new role after redundancy. I interviewed with two places.

(A) is a 12 month contract, great vibe, lots of learning opportunities and well-known. It would be ideal in many ways. I've passed the interviews, they asked for references, from what I gathered, there's me and another person that they are deciding between.

(B) is a 3 month contract, great vibe, but not so great on the learning front and not a well-known place. They want to move forward with me, and asked about my contract rate and start date.

I wanted to stall a bit, hold out to hear back from (A), but the answer didn't come yet. It will probably be decided in the next few days.

Both go through recruiters, and I told both recruiters about the other place. Recruiter (B) will call me first thing on Monday and they want an answer.

Should I go ahead and try to negotiate (and stall) with B for another day or two?

I don't want to waste anyone's time.
I also know that I'd kick myself for missing out on (A) due to (B) if they did indeed chose me. But I don't want to risk a sure thing either, and pass on (B) when I might not be selected for (A).

Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: With a 3 month contract, depending on the situation, you could almost do (B) and still accept (A) with a delayed starting date

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear that you actually have a real offer on the table yet, so this may all be jumping the gun anyway. But let's assume you could get an acceptable offer from B on Monday.

> Recruiter (B) will call me first thing on Monday and they want an
> answer.
>
> Should I go ahead and try to negotiate (and stall) with B for another
> day or two?

Well, B says they want an answer. If you think you will get away with asking for more time, do it.

The risk is that they will give up on you and move on to another candidate. You get to decide if you are willing to take that risk or not.

> I don't want to waste anyone's time.

You don't need to worry about other people's time. Just worry about your own.

> I also know that I'd kick myself for missing out on (A) due to (B) if
> they did indeed chose me. But I don't want to risk a sure thing
> either, and pass on (B) when I might not be selected for (A).

If you are very risk averse, accept the offer from B, tell A that you are now off the market, and don't look back.

But if you have any confidence in yourself, try to postpone B, and take the risk that you will lose their offer. If that happens, you might get an offer from A that is acceptable, or you might not.

IMHO, there is always a company C. If you have enough confidence in yourself, decide that you can take the risk on A, but eventually you will land a good job - with C, D, E, or someplace else.

Answer (score 2):

> (A) is a 12 month contract
> (B) is a 3 month contract

These are temp jobs, so it depends on when the project start date is. On the start date they will expect you to start or they lose money for each day there is not body in the chair.
From my experience, recruiters will call me up 3-4 days before they expect me to start on site across the country (like call me on Friday at 7 pm & expect me there Monday morning).

However, there could be months between the start date & first interview.

The solution is, ask the project start date & then subtract 4 days & you have your stalling time.