# I have received an affirmative, but I am still in the final stages of several application processes - how to maximize ones options?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, applications

From my first application, I got an affirmative via phone some days ago and an e-mail with details about my salary, bonuses and so on. The interview was good, for the role, I am a great match from my profile and it is my PhD niche. But the position is only EG15, not EG16. Two different ranges in Germany with a difference of around 10k per year.

For this reason, I want to take the chance and try to get further offers from other companies to find an EG16 position. Therefore, I guess I will have time around the end of next week. They will send me my job contract and then I have to sign and send it back or reject. So probably just one week to get further offers.

- Would you inform the recruiter that you are still in order
  application processes involved and want to wait until their goal?
- How can I get some extra time for finishing the other processes without telling them the truth?
- Would you inform the other recruiters so that they can speed up their processes or is this not a good idea?
- I want the company and the manager think that I really only want that company and position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: Did you ask specifically for an EG16 position?

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing holding you back from the position that you have the offer from is EG15 vs. EG16, you may want to discuss this with the recruiter to see if an acceptable compromise or adjustment can be made by the company.

Some options that come to my mind:

1. The company agrees to bring you on at EG16.
2. The company agrees to conditionally bring you on at EG16 and if your performance after 6 months or so warrants it, you remain at that level, otherwise you fall back to EG15.
3. The company agree to bring you on at EG15 but if your performance at 6 months or so warrants it, you get a promotion to EG16.
4. The company brings you on at EG15 but your salary is closer to EG16.

I'm sure there are other possibilities but you always get 100% of what you don't ask for.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you inform the recruiter that you are still in order application processes involved and want to wait until their goal?

No. It's unlikely to make a difference. The offer is on the table and once you are at this stage it's mostly "take it or leave it". Any negotiations around start date, time line, compensation should happen before that.

> How can I get some extra time for finishing the other processes without telling them the truth?

You can't.

> Would you inform the other recruiters so that they can speed up their processes or is this not a good idea?

Yes. That's a perfectly valid reason to speed up the process. In some cases it will help, in other's it won't.

> I want the company and the manager think that I really only want that company and position.

Understandable but it's not actually the full truth, isn't it?  I would simply not mention that you are still looking and they can draw their own conclusions. Don't lie though: if someone asks point blank you should answer truthfully.

In a week or so you will have to make a difficult decision. Take the offer in-hand or decline and keep looking for more money. It's not easy call, but it's very common during the job search.