# Is it polite to keep a contract offer "on hold" while I wait for other offers to potentially materialize?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, germany

I am in the process of changing jobs.

I have sent my CV around quite a bit in the last months and I finally landed some interviews.
Most of them have been for the same company, but different departments/daughter companies, so all with different managers, hiring personell, and different locations.

Some interviews I got by submitting my CV to the company for the positions they published on their portal, others I got through a consultancy company to which I gave my CV before those positions opened.

I would favour a position that is also a direct hire, but if that does not materialize, I would probably take the consultancy position rather than being unemployed.

Now, it seems that I might receive more than one offer, but given the situation, the procedure via the consultancy company seems that it will go much faster.

This a completely new situation for me and I don't know what is good or bad etiquette.
My gut feeling tells me that, no matter what's written on the contract about trial period and being able to walk away with no repercussions in the first 6 months, if I sign contract A today, to be started in 3-4 months, I should not turn around a few weeks later and say "you know what, yes I signed, but I want to quit even before I start, because now I got offer B that I prefer".

So, I think I could boil down my question to the folowing:
in Germany (or in Europe, if you prefer giving other perspectives, but I am not overly interested in a US scenario, because in my understanding the culture is significantly different), is it polite to keep an offer on hold for some days? How straightforward/honest/direct can I be without antagonizing the people extending me the offer?

I have read this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111) (and its answers) and I appreciate what it means to my situation. Here I am looking for information on how the local culture might affect the answers given there, as well as the fact that here I am dealing with different elements of the same macro-company, rather than different companies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time I experienced this, I too was nervous.

The General rule of thumb is that once you have received an Offer (in writing, verbal offers aren't worth the paper they are printed on ;) ) - you have up to 1-2 weeks to accept or decline.

Essentially:

"Thank you very much for your offer - it's a generous offer, with lots to consider, I will respond to you by the end of this week/end of next week" (changing to whichever is applicable).

I personally will go to the end of the Working week, e.g. if I got an Offer on Monday, I would tell them that I would respond by the end of that week, but if it was say a Thursday, end of next week.

It is acceptable during this time to talk to the other people you are in negotiation with:

"Just so you know, I have an offer on the table, I've committed to giving a response by *date* - if you want to proceed, please send through a written offer prior to *date*"

The key aspect is to keep the timeframe short (1-2 weeks max) and to set a date *and stick to it* in the first instance. If you get other offers during this time, they have to be evaluated in the timeframe set by the first offer (unless you decline that offer).